# iMac eventually crashing after memory upgrade

Tags: imac, upgrade, memory, crash

I have an iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2010) running on two pairs of brand new VALUESELECT Corsair memories - 4 slots, 4GB each.

OSX (both Mountain Lion and Yosemite) is detecting available memory accordingly - 16 GB 1333 MHz DDR3. But it will suddenly crash, with no explicit link with an app or activity. Returned the old 2GB memories, it works just fine again.

*- I wonder if anyone can point me a direction on how could I solve this thing.*

So there goes the crash log:

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff801a7ccfca): "vm_object_iopl_request: missing/bad page in kernel object\n"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2782.1.97/osfmk/vm/vm_pageout.c:7790
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8201f83190 : 0xffffff801a73a811 
0xffffff8201f83210 : 0xffffff801a7ccfca 
0xffffff8201f835b0 : 0xffffff801a7cc504 
0xffffff8201f83690 : 0xffffff801ace83e3 
0xffffff8201f837b0 : 0xffffff801ace86b1 
0xffffff8201f837e0 : 0xffffff7f9ae53e26 
0xffffff8201f838b0 : 0xffffff801a985445 
0xffffff8201f83910 : 0xffffff801a92bfe3 
0xffffff8201f83a60 : 0xffffff801a92e347 
0xffffff8201f83af0 : 0xffffff801ab48022 
0xffffff8201f83b40 : 0xffffff801a92dda8 
0xffffff8201f83b90 : 0xffffff801a97e712 
0xffffff8201f83ca0 : 0xffffff801a97d69a 
0xffffff8201f83d50 : 0xffffff801a97bc34 
0xffffff8201f83da0 : 0xffffff801ab60ff1 
0xffffff8201f83dd0 : 0xffffff801ab5804f 
0xffffff8201f83eb0 : 0xffffff801a95c86b 
0xffffff8201f83ed0 : 0xffffff801a946ef4 
0xffffff8201f83f40 : 0xffffff801a9510f7 
0xffffff8201f83f50 : 0xffffff801ac4dcb2 
0xffffff8201f83fb0 : 0xffffff801a83ac46 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.0)[8C420771-7171-3369-891C-6E24F60E569E]@0xffffff7f9ae47000->0xffffff7f9ae6cfff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: launchd

Mac OS version:
14A389

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 89E10306-BC78-3A3B-955C-7C4922577E61
Kernel slide:     0x000000001a400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801a600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801a500000
System model name: iMac11,2 (Mac-F2238AC8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 2954286348943
last loaded kext at 289724587107: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f9ccf8000, size 69632)
last unloaded kext at 459631100989: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f9ccf8000, size 61440)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   85.3
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.37
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.0f10
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.ATIRadeonX2000    10.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMD4600Controller    1.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.4.12
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.10
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.2b3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Atheros40  700.74.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  175.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   175.5
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  260.30
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 266.5
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   200.6
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.0f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.0f10
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 266.5
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.0d49
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.2.8
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.7.21
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   700.52
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 389.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Unable to gather system configuration information.Model: iMac11,2, BootROM IM112.0057.B01, 2 processors, Intel Core i3, 3.06 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 1.64f5
Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 4670, ATI Radeon HD 4670, PCIe, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D534F344758334D314131333333433920
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D534F344758334D314131333333433920
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D534F344758334D314131333333433920
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D534F344758334D314131333333433920
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x8F), Atheros 9280: 4.0.74.0-P2P
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.0f10 14890, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD5000AAKS-40V6A0, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-STDVDRW  GA32N
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

**Anything will help, a lot :)**

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much answered your own question, "...crashing after memory upgrade."

Remove the DIMMs one at a time until the crashing stops, then try **just** what you think is the bad DIMM and see if it still crashes.

It is possible that there is a bad DIMM slot unless they were all full with smaller DIMMs previously but the safe money here is one (or more) of the DIMMS is bad.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I tested the memories in pairs, as they were bought in pairs and should be replaced in pairs. This cut the work in a half. Additionally, I used my previous working memories to ensure both pairs of iMac slots were working. So, after this, I will order a replacement today, it's a hardware issue indeed. Thanks very much!